# XUnit test for file upload causes an exception though the endpoint works when used in my site

Tags: c#, api, restsharp, asp.net-core-2.1

Using insomnia to create the code with RestSharp:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://localhost:44372/api/Box/Upload");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001", "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"LiterallyAnything\"\r\n\r\n", ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddFile("MyFileName", "MyFileAndPath");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

This hits the .net Core 2.1 endpoint just fine:

```
[HttpPost("Upload")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ActionResult), 201)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ActionResult), 400)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ActionResult), 500)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload() {
    ActionResult retVal = StatusCode(500);
    try {
        if (Request.Form.Files.Count() != 1) { //<----Throws exception here
```

I get the following error:

```
Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.
```

I've checked to see if there's some kind of file lock (there isn't). The file absolutely exists. It just doesn't seem to handle it too well when running from within the unit test.

What gives?

Comment: Please share your test method, so that we can reproduce and troubleshoot the issue better. Besides, please not that [unit tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/#what-are-unit-tests) should only test code within the developer’s control, they should not test infrastructure concerns. Writing [integration tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#introduction-to-integration-tests) for file uploads would be better.

Comment: The first snippet of code is literally the test (sans asserts). We're also running an actual automated test front to back because it's going to our endpoint which uploads via the Box.com API SDK which has crap documentation, has a notable amount of breaking changes on updates and we frequently have network changes that break things and a full test like this is going to tell us if a network change, a code change, or a Box.com API change is the cause. I know best practices here and that's not what I asked about though I appreciate the concern.

Comment: Why are you adding headers to the request if `AddFile` does it all for you automatically?

Comment: ...wait, it does? BRB, gonna go check that out. (To answer that directly, the code is generated by Insomnia and the calls work within insomnia. So maybe the real question is "Why are they generating headers instead of doing an AddFile??")

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev, put that as an answer. Removing that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use any overload of `IRestRequest.AddFile`, it will add a special type of parameter to the request, called `FileParameter`. When the `RestClient` discovers that the list of files in the request is not empty, it will form a mult-part form request automatically for you and set all the necessary headers.

In general, there is a very little number of cases when you need to manually add headers and technical parameters to your requests when using RestSharp. Hence that nowhere in the documentation we add things like the content type to the request headers as it is always done automatically for you based on the request parameters, body, files and so on.

Concerning the Insomnia client, they use the `httpsnippet` tool from Kong to generate code snippets. [This is their code](https://github.com/Kong/httpsnippet/blob/master/src/targets/csharp/restsharp.js) for RestSharp, which is extremely simplistic and definitely doesn't fit our recommended usage, so I would recommend checking our [docs](http://restsharp.org).

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the link as I tighten up the code.